# How can I erase the intersection between cube and cylinder within a drawing?

Tags: diagrams, 3d

Is there a possibility to define a volume (i.e. cylinder) for erease this part of a 3D-drawing consisting of several elements?

[image: cutted intersected volume part]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what you want to do, and in what context, could you try to clarify?

Comment: Hi, I will try to explain more accurate.
I want to draw a layered stack. First layer: eight single strips; second: a solid layer and third: again eight single strips - but rotated.
After this I want to cut a part of the whole volume to show the first layer.

Comment: Isn't that what you've got?

Comment: The sort answer is no.  What you have to do is construct the layer with the hole already in it.